# Location of roots of quadratic equation

Tags: determinant

> Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ such that no two of them are equal and
>   satisfy $$\det\begin{bmatrix}2a&b&c\\b&c&2a\\c&2a&b\end{bmatrix} = 0 ,$$
>   then the equation $24ax^2 + 4bx +c=0$ has:
>
> a) atleast one root in $[0,\frac 12]$
>
> b) at least one root in $[-\frac 12, 0)$
>
> c) at least one root in $[1,2]$
>
> d) none of these

On solving the determinant equation I have obtained $2a+b+c =0$ but I am not sure how that is of any help.  because I am uanble to transform the given equation in  $x$  to $2a+b+c= 0$ for any $x$. How do I proceed?

**Edit:**

Using @AnotherJohnDoe's suggestion, if we let $c=0$, we get $b=-2a$ after solving the determinant equation.

On substituting these values into the quadratic equation, 
we get:

$-12bx^2 + 4bx = 0$

which has roots $\dfrac 13$ and $0$ so we get option A/D. But there doesn't seem to be a way to eliminate option D. So there must be another solution to this question?

Comment: $2a+b+c$ is the trace of that matrix, not its determinant, which is $-8 a^3 + 6 a b c - b^3 - c^3$.

Comment: @Ihf $-8a^3 -b^3 -c^3 = -6abc \implies 2a + b+ c =0$

Comment: @Ihf I never said that $2a+b+c$ is the value of the determinant.

Comment: Could you explain how you got $2a+b+c=0$? [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-8+a%5E3+%2B+6+a+b+c+-+b%5E3+-+c%5E3%3D0) tells me that $-8 a^3 + 6 a b c - b^3 - c^3=-(2 a + b + c) (4 a^2 - 2 a b - 2 a c + b^2 - b c + c^2)$

Comment: @lhf This quadratic factor is irreducible over the reals... It only remains $2a+b+c =0$.

Comment: Let $A=2a$, then the determinant has the one factor $A+b+c$, the other being $A^2+b^2+c^2-Ab-bc-cA\ge 0$, equality when $A=b=c$, excluded... (There is also a $(-1)$ factor.)

Comment: We have an explicit formula for the roots in terms of $a,b$, $c$ being given by $-b-2a$. Then we can further norm by homogenity $a=1$. It remains to examine the function $b\to (-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+6b+12})/12$. (Or something similar, it was a quick computation. Letting $b\to 0_+$ excludes the case (c). Letting $b\to\pm\infty$...)

Comment: If this holds for arbitrary values of $a,b,c$, why not let $c=0?$

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe See my edit.

Comment: Isn't option $A$ then the answer?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe it does not exclude the possibility of option D.

Comment: Hmm, the question reads as - If $a,b,c$ satisfy $2a+b+c=0$, then it satisfies one of options $A$ through $D$. Doesn't it then follow that $A$ must be the solution?

Comment: The quadratic polynomial $f(x)= 24 a x^2+4 b x+c$ has both roots greater than $1/2$ if and only if $a f(1/2)>0 $ and the sum of the roots is greater than $1$. Similarly, it has two negative roots if and only if $a f(0)>0 $ and the sum of the roots is negative. Show neither is possible so $f$ must have a root between $0$ and $1/2$

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe We have just checked for c=0 . How can we claim Option A is correct for all possible combinations of a b and c?

Comment: I was saying that the phrasing of the question suggested one of the four options was true for all valid values of $a,b,c$. Since it was true for a particular case, it would them imply it being true for all valid values

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=24ax^2+4bx+c$

Suppose $f(0)\gt0$. Then it follows $c\gt0$. Now, $f(\frac 12)=6a+2b+c=2a-c$. If $f(\frac 12)\gt0,$ then $2a\gt c\gt 0.$

Then $f(\frac 14)=\frac{24}{16}a+b+c=-\frac 12a<0.\\$

Similarly, if $f(0)\lt 0$, then $c\lt 0$. If $f(\frac 12)=2a-c\lt0$, then $2a\lt c\lt 0\Rightarrow f(\frac 14)=-\frac 12\gt 0$.